# encapsulating some routes to other component in react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I m using react and i have app.js like this:

```
function App() {
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => { ... setData([1,2,3]);}, []);

return (
<Router>
<Routes>
 <Route element={<SomeElement/>}>
 <Route index exact path="/path1" element={<SomeComponent data={data}/>}/>
 <Route path="/path2" element={<AnotherComponent data={data}/>}/>
</Routes>
<Router/>);
}
```

I just want to move routes, which are using data to separate component, since i want to load data only if i need.

I would like to see something like this:

```
function SeparateRoutes(){
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => { ... setData([1,2,3]);}, []);

return <Fragment>
 <Route index exact path="/" element={<SomeComponent data={data}/>}/>
 <Route path="/path" element={<AnotherComponent data={data}/>}/> </Fragment>;
}

function App() {

return (
<Router>
<Routes>
 <SeparateRoutes/>
 <Route index exact path="/" element={<SomeComponent data={data}/>}/>
 <Route path="/path" element={<AnotherComponent data={data}/>}/>
</Routes>
<Router/>);
}
```

I`ve tried this variant but there is an error: component children must be a Route or React.Fragment

Comment: Are the routes rendered by `SeparateRoutes` *really* just completely separate routes, unrelated to any routes in `App`? `SeparateRoutes` appears to be rendering routes on duplicate paths, is this accurate? Can you [edit] to include a more accurate [mcve] for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Drew, most of the pages, which are rendered, are separate from pages in app.js. but there is an index page, which is also using specific data. Maybe the order of routes is not correct in example.

Comment: Well, its not a case, i have changed route paths to different now, is there any way to separate routes into components?

Comment: why you close ```<Router />``` ? where is ```Routes ```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to split the code up a bit and render routes separately in components then each set of `Route` components need to be rendered in a `Routes` component.

Example:

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function SeparateRoutes() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    ...
    setData([1, 2, 3]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/path1" element={<SomeComponent data={data} />} />
      <Route path="/path2" element={<AnotherComponent data={data} />} /> 
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Make sure you aren't accidentally rendering a self-closed `Router` component tag, it should wrap all the routes and UI content that needs to access the routing context it provides.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <SeparateRoutes />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<SomeComponent />} />
        <Route path="/path" element={<AnotherComponent />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

If you only want data to be fetched for specific routes you might also try creating a layout route and rendering nested routes instead of an entirely separate component with descendent routes.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

function DataLayout() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    ...
    setData([1, 2, 3]);
  }, []);

  // Pass data state in Outlet context
  return <Outlet context={data} />;
}
```

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<SomeComponent />} />
        <Route path="/path" element={<AnotherComponent />} />
        <Route element={<DataLayout />}>
          <Route path="/path1" element={<SomeComponent />} />
          <Route path="/path2" element={<AnotherComponent />} /> 
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```
import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

export const AnotherComponent = () => {
  const data = useOutletContext();

  ...
};
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much. Did not know that i can use not one but more Routes in Router

Comment: @Moonkjo You can render as many `Routes` components as you need to structure/organize routes and content. I've also just updated my answer to include an alternative using the `Outlet` component so you don't need to split the routes up in separate components.